# How to understand this code of programming a DSP?

Tags: c, embedded, signal-processing, microcontroller, processor

My "Introduction to Digital Signal Processor" course is using C2000 Piccolo Launchpad to teach digital signal processors.

At present, I am totally lost. Coz, my instructor is seemingly not interested to provide us any material to study at home.

For example,

The following code is from Texas Instrument's [controlSUITE](http://www.ti.com/tool/controlsuite?DCMP=piccolo-led&HQS=piccolo-led-pr-tf3) package.

```
//########################################################################
//
//  File:   f2802x_examples/timed_led_blink/Example_F2802xLedBlink.c
//
//  Title:  F2802x LED Blink Getting Started Program.
//
//  Group:          C2000
//  Target Device:  TMS320F2802x
//
//! \addtogroup example_list
//!  <h1>LED Blink</h1>
//!
//!   This example configures CPU Timer0 for a 500 msec period, and toggles 
//!   the GPIO0-4 LEDs  once per interrupt. For testing purposes, this example
//!   also increments a counter each time the timer asserts an interrupt.
//!
//!   Watch Variables:
//!   - interruptCount
//!
//!   Monitor the GPIO0-4 LEDs blink on (for 500 msec) and off (for 500 msec) 
//!   on the 2802x0 control card.
//
//  (C) Copyright 2012, Texas Instruments, Inc.
//#############################################################################
// $TI Release: PACKAGE NAME $
// $Release Date: PACKAGE RELEASE DATE $
//#############################################################################

#include "DSP28x_Project.h"   // Device Headerfile and Examples Include File

#include "f2802x_common/include/adc.h"
#include "f2802x_common/include/clk.h"
#include "f2802x_common/include/flash.h"
#include "f2802x_common/include/gpio.h"
#include "f2802x_common/include/pie.h"
#include "f2802x_common/include/pll.h"
#include "f2802x_common/include/timer.h"
#include "f2802x_common/include/wdog.h"

// Prototype statements for functions found within this file.
__interrupt void cpu_timer0_isr(void);

uint16_t interruptCount = 0;

ADC_Handle myAdc;
CLK_Handle myClk;
FLASH_Handle myFlash;
GPIO_Handle myGpio;
PIE_Handle myPie;
TIMER_Handle myTimer;

void main(void)
{

    CPU_Handle myCpu;
    PLL_Handle myPll;
    WDOG_Handle myWDog;

    // Initialize all the handles needed for this application    
    myAdc = ADC_init((void *)ADC_BASE_ADDR, sizeof(ADC_Obj));
    myClk = CLK_init((void *)CLK_BASE_ADDR, sizeof(CLK_Obj));
    myCpu = CPU_init((void *)NULL, sizeof(CPU_Obj));
    myFlash = FLASH_init((void *)FLASH_BASE_ADDR, sizeof(FLASH_Obj));
    myGpio = GPIO_init((void *)GPIO_BASE_ADDR, sizeof(GPIO_Obj));
    myPie = PIE_init((void *)PIE_BASE_ADDR, sizeof(PIE_Obj));
    myPll = PLL_init((void *)PLL_BASE_ADDR, sizeof(PLL_Obj));
    myTimer = TIMER_init((void *)TIMER0_BASE_ADDR, sizeof(TIMER_Obj));
    myWDog = WDOG_init((void *)WDOG_BASE_ADDR, sizeof(WDOG_Obj));

    // Perform basic system initialization    
    WDOG_disable(myWDog);
    CLK_enableAdcClock(myClk);
    (*Device_cal)();

    //Select the internal oscillator 1 as the clock source
    CLK_setOscSrc(myClk, CLK_OscSrc_Internal);

    // Setup the PLL for x10 /2 which will yield 50Mhz = 10Mhz * 10 / 2
    PLL_setup(myPll, PLL_Multiplier_10, PLL_DivideSelect_ClkIn_by_2);

    // Disable the PIE and all interrupts
    PIE_disable(myPie);
    PIE_disableAllInts(myPie);
    CPU_disableGlobalInts(myCpu);
    CPU_clearIntFlags(myCpu);

    // If running from flash copy RAM only functions to RAM   
#ifdef _FLASH
    memcpy(&RamfuncsRunStart, &RamfuncsLoadStart, (size_t)&RamfuncsLoadSize);
#endif      

    // Setup a debug vector table and enable the PIE
    PIE_setDebugIntVectorTable(myPie);
    PIE_enable(myPie);

    // Register interrupt handlers in the PIE vector table
    PIE_registerPieIntHandler(myPie, PIE_GroupNumber_1, PIE_SubGroupNumber_7, (intVec_t)&cpu_timer0_isr);

    // Configure CPU-Timer 0 to interrupt every 500 milliseconds:
    // 60MHz CPU Freq, 50 millisecond Period (in uSeconds)
    //    ConfigCpuTimer(&CpuTimer0, 60, 500000);
    TIMER_stop(myTimer);
    TIMER_setPeriod(myTimer, 50 * 500000);
    TIMER_setPreScaler(myTimer, 0);
    TIMER_reload(myTimer);
    TIMER_setEmulationMode(myTimer, TIMER_EmulationMode_StopAfterNextDecrement);
    TIMER_enableInt(myTimer);

    TIMER_start(myTimer);    

    // Configure GPIO 0-3 as outputs
    GPIO_setMode(myGpio, GPIO_Number_0, GPIO_0_Mode_GeneralPurpose);
    GPIO_setMode(myGpio, GPIO_Number_1, GPIO_0_Mode_GeneralPurpose);
    GPIO_setMode(myGpio, GPIO_Number_2, GPIO_0_Mode_GeneralPurpose);
    GPIO_setMode(myGpio, GPIO_Number_3, GPIO_0_Mode_GeneralPurpose);

    GPIO_setDirection(myGpio, GPIO_Number_0, GPIO_Direction_Output);
    GPIO_setDirection(myGpio, GPIO_Number_1, GPIO_Direction_Output);
    GPIO_setDirection(myGpio, GPIO_Number_2, GPIO_Direction_Output);
    GPIO_setDirection(myGpio, GPIO_Number_3, GPIO_Direction_Output);

    GPIO_setLow(myGpio, GPIO_Number_0);
    GPIO_setHigh(myGpio, GPIO_Number_1);
    GPIO_setLow(myGpio, GPIO_Number_2);
    GPIO_setHigh(myGpio, GPIO_Number_3);

    // Enable CPU INT1 which is connected to CPU-Timer 0:
    CPU_enableInt(myCpu, CPU_IntNumber_1);

    // Enable TINT0 in the PIE: Group 1 interrupt 7
    PIE_enableTimer0Int(myPie);

    // Enable global Interrupts and higher priority real-time debug events
    CPU_enableGlobalInts(myCpu);
    CPU_enableDebugInt(myCpu);

    for(;;){
        __asm(" NOP");
    }

}    

__interrupt void cpu_timer0_isr(void)
{
    interruptCount++;

    // Toggle GPIOs
    GPIO_toggle(myGpio, GPIO_Number_0);
    GPIO_toggle(myGpio, GPIO_Number_1);
    GPIO_toggle(myGpio, GPIO_Number_2);
    GPIO_toggle(myGpio, GPIO_Number_3);

    // Acknowledge this interrupt to receive more interrupts from group 1
    PIE_clearInt(myPie, PIE_GroupNumber_1);
} 

//===========================================================================
// No more.
//===========================================================================
```

As I can see, there are lots of things going on here. But, I am finding no place to learn the basics of coding C2000.

I have some basic questions:

(1) What does `__interrupt` and `__asm` keywords do? Where can I find the reference for those keywords?

(2) How do I know that how many handles I need? For example, for this LED blinking application, they have declared 9 handles. Why?

(3) What is a "Base Address"?

(4) Why is WachDog disabled? Why are PIE and CPU and their interrupts disabled?

(5) What is timer-prescalar?

(6) What is timer-emulation-mode?

(7) What does GPIO_setmode do? What is the mode about?

**(8) Where can I start to learn all these details?**

Is this a good material to start with or the waste of time? http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru430f/spru430f.pdf

Comment: Read datasheet, API documentation, compiler docs and programming manual. This is definitely not a right place to seek info on that.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  where should I ask in SE ?

Comment: You shouldn't. It will be too broad for any SE network site.

Comment: __asm and __interrupt are obviously language extentions; look them up in your compiler manual. The rest (functions and defines) can probably be found in the included header files, or in the hardware documentation (the subdevices and their usage).

Comment: Embedded programming is an art, and one that takes time and patience.  You can try checking out Adafruit for some introductory lessons on how *general-purpose input/output* (GPIO) works, among other things.  As for how various interrupts work and the like - keep an eye out for "Application Notes" from manufacturers.  They usually provide sample/example programs you can interpret out of.

Comment: @tonysdg    Is this a good material to start with or the waste of time?

http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru430f/spru430f.pdf

Comment: @tonysdg  I just need to pass the course at the moment.

Comment: @anonymous - You're probably going to need a combination of that document, the datasheet from [this](http://www.ti.com/tool/launchxl-f28027#Technical Documents) page, and the Application notes from the same page.  Start with high level ideas - how do GPIO/interrupts work in general (a textbook will help here) - and then drill down into how it works on your specific platform.

Comment: @tonysdg Whenever I hear of programming being an art... I unlock my Browning! (Slightly modified (c)Hanns Johst). Programming is an *Engineering* and applied *Science*. Unless people understand that, we will continue getting different versions of software crisis.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - I'm not 100% sure that I understand your line of reasoning...how does calling an engineering an art lead to poorly designed software?

Comment: @tonysdg Art implies (at least how I see it) that every programmer is an artist. Artist is a person who kind of.. creating whatever he likes and however he likes, ignoring any boundaries, guidelines, standards and common techniques. Which is good for an art. But devastating for engineering.

Comment: @EugeneSh.     Hey bros, please, take it elsewhere.... Give us some space to breathe.

Comment: @tonysdg  Hey bros, please, take it elsewhere.... Give us some space to breathe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What does __interrupt and __asm keywords do? Where can I find the reference for those keywords?

`__interrupt` tells the compiler to wrap the function with code appropriate for the platform, typically to save and restore registers that the function uses so the interrupted code is not affected, and to return with a "return from interrupt" instruction rather than a "return from subroutine" instruction

`__asm` tells the compiler to insert a machine level instruction in the output of the compiler before it is sent to the assembler

2. How do I know that how many handles I need? For example, for this LED blinking application, they have declared 9 handles. Why?

Because the code uses those nine hardware subsystems, as defined by the TI libraries and header files

3. What is a "Base Address"?

In the hardware, there are groups of resisters that control hardware functions such as I/O, timers, etc. Each group of registers is assigned a memory range, starting at the base address. There may be several identical groups, e.g., several timers. By using a base address for each group, the code to handle that function, e.g., a timer, can be shared among all the instances.

4. Why is WachDog disabled? Why are PIE and CPU and their interrupts disabled?

I suspect that whatever initialization is being performed takes longer than the watchdog interval, so it is disabled to prevent the CPU from being reset by the watchdog

5. What is timer-prescalar?

It is a divider of the timer's source clock to create an appropriate resolution and range for the timer

6. What is timer-emulation-mode?

I don't know. Perhaps it's just a weird name for "mode." Or maybe it is a legacy mode.

7. What does GPIO_setmode do? What is the mode about?

The GPIO hardware must have options to, e.g., attach an interrupt to an edge, or change slew rates or hysteresis, or any of a number of things.

8. Where can I start to learn all these details?

C2000 Piccolo Reference Manual
C2000 Piccolo Data Sheet
Compiler documentation
controlSUITE package documentation

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer when people are advising me to go elsewhere or voting to close. http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru430f/spru430f.pdf ...  Is this a good material to start with or the waste of time? Coz, I have only 2 months to my final exam.

Comment: You also want http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sprs523j/sprs523j.pdf

Comment: (4) Why is PIE disabled and then enabled again later?

Comment: PIE is disabled while the vector table is being changed to prevent an interrupt from using a partially updated table. It seems prudent! It may also be the transition from disabled to enabled that causes to the PIE to reset some things internally and read the table (I haven't checked the docs on that point).

Answer (score 1):

All the questions you've asked are related to the specific details of the processor this code is written for. The best way to get an answer to your questions is therefore to look in the datasheet for the 'C2000 Piccolo TMS320F28027 MCU' since this is the microcontroller used by the C2000 Piccolo Launchpad evaluation platform. The datasheet can be downloaded directly from Texas Instrument's webpage via this link: http://www.ti.com/tool/launchxl-f28027.

I will provide some short answers to some of your questions based on what I already know about microcontrollers in general. I give no guarantees that this information is correct, as I previously wrote, in order to be sure you will have to read the datasheet. This document should also help you get started: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruhh2a/spruhh2a.pdf.

1:
The `__interrupt` keyword probably sets up the tagged function as an *Interrupt Service Routine* (ISR) for the specified interrupt, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler.

The `__asm` keyword activates inline assembly enabling you to directly write processor specific assembly instructions in the C-code.

3:
The base address might refer to the memory address of memory-mapped i/o-devices and control registers.

4:
A watchdog is a sort of timer that you will have to reset periodically. If this is not done it is an indication that your program may be frozen in which case the watchdog can trigger a soft reset of the microcontroller. The interrupts are probably disabled simply because they are not needed by this demo application.

8:
There are lots of resources online if you just google a little ;)
I would start by reading through all the material listed under 'Technical Documents' here: http://www.ti.com/tool/launchxl-f28027.

Comment: (4) Why is PIE disabled and then enabled again later?

Answer (score 1):

1.

`__interrupt` and `__asm` are code markups to denote interrupt function cpu_timer0_isr (interrupt service routine) and assembler code.

2.

This depends upon what do you want to achieve, what do you need to read from the  device.

3.

`...BASE_ADDR` are addresses in memory of the locations where to read/write to drive device. In particular `ADC_BASE_ADDR` [defines](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruhx9/spruhx9.pdf) the base address of the analog-to-digital converter (ADC) registers.

4.

[Watchdogs](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms320f28027.pdf) are used to monitor some activity. In TMS320F2802x and TMS320F2802xx family

> Each device contains two watchdogs: CPU-Watchdog that monitors the core
>   and NMI-Watchdog that is a missing clock-detect circuit. The user
>   software must regularly reset the CPU-watchdog counter within a
>   certain time frame; otherwise, the CPU-watchdog generates a reset to
>   the processor. The CPU-watchdog can be disabled if necessary. The
>   NMI-Watchdog engages only in case of a clock failure and can either
>   generate an interrupt or a device reset.

NMI stands for non-maskable-interrupts:

```
cat /proc/interrupts
```

on Linux to see their counter on each CPU.

5.

Please read [Doug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33814919/1141471) for the rest of the answers.

Comment: (4) Why is PIE disabled and then enabled again later?